# How to use bootstrap-sass rake convert to create SASS version of Bootstrap v3.0.0

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, rake, yeoman

I have project that I scaffolded using yeoman with angular generator. I'm using the bootstrap SASS functionality provided by https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass. I have a bootstrap theme that I would like to use, which was built against bootstrap v3.0.0. The latest version of bootstrap-sass is v3.2.0 and there is no version in the repo that corresponds to bootstrap v.3.0.0. So I'm trying to follow the instructions at https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass under **Upstream Converter** to convert the bootstrap 3.0.0 less into SASS. When I run "rake convert", everything seems to work fine. However, when I run "rake convert[e8a1df5f060bf7e6631554648e0abde150aedbe4]" as listed in the example, I get following error from rake:

```
Convert Bootstrap LESS to SASS
 repo   : https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap
 branch : e8a1df5f060bf7e6631554648e0abde150aedbe4 https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/e8a1df5f060bf7e6631554648e0abde150aedbe4
 save to: {"js":"assets/javascripts/bootstrap","scss":"assets/stylesheets/bootstrap","fonts":"assets/fonts/bootstrap"}
 twbs cache: tmp/converter-cache-bootstrap
------------------------------------------------------------
Processing fonts...
  CACHED GET https://api.github.com/repos/twbs/bootstrap/git/trees/e8a1df5f060bf7e6631554648e0abde150aedbe4...
  CACHED GET https://api.github.com/repos/twbs/bootstrap/git/trees/7285f3ab6cb0aa40e75282615ae459af6ba00101...
  CACHED GET 4 files from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/twbs/bootstrap/e8a1df5f060bf7e6631554648e0abde150aedbe4/fonts glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff...
Processing stylesheets...
  CACHED GET https://api.github.com/repos/twbs/bootstrap/git/trees/c4320c56cf62c962f7d150c7b5777379e20f83d2...
  CACHED GET https://api.github.com/repos/twbs/bootstrap/git/trees/c4320c56cf62c962f7d150c7b5777379e20f83d2...
rake aborted!
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
/home/apal/dev/bootstrap-sass/tasks/converter/network.rb:71:in `get_tree_sha'
/home/apal/dev/bootstrap-sass/tasks/converter/less_conversion.rb:142:in `bootstrap_less_files'
/home/apal/dev/bootstrap-sass/tasks/converter/less_conversion.rb:54:in `process_stylesheet_assets'
/home/apal/dev/bootstrap-sass/tasks/converter.rb:63:in `process_bootstrap'
/home/apal/dev/bootstrap-sass/Rakefile:16:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/apal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/apal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => convert
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I'm not too familiar with ruby, so I'm not sure where to start. Curious if anyone can get this to work. Possibly there is something wrong with my ruby environment. My current ruby version is:

$ ruby -v

ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-linux]

$ rake -V

rake, version 10.1.0

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem will be caused by older versions (<3.2) not having a less/mixins directory. Reading the files from less/mixins is "hard coded", commenting out these lines (less_conversion.rb) seems to fix the issue for now:

```
def bootstrap_less_files
  @bootstrap_less_files ||= get_paths_by_type('less', /\.less$/) 
  #+
  #  get_paths_by_type('mixins', /\.less$/,
  #                    get_tree(get_tree_sha('mixins', get_tree(get_tree_sha('less'))))).map { |p| "mixins/#{p}" }
end
```

see also: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/issues/735